# Cannot update nor remove maridb

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I made a mistake. I had to update mariadb.
So did:

> sudo apt-get install mariadb-server
>
> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
> state information... Done You might want to run 'apt-get -f install'
> to correct these: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
> mariadb-client : Depends: mariadb-client-10.0 (=
> 10.0.33+maria-1~trusty) but 10.0.31-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 is to be installed  mariadb-server : Depends: mariadb-server-10.2 (>=
> 10.2.7+maria~xenial) but it is not going to be installed E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a
> solution).

And then tried to remove as I got errors:

> Reading package
> lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading state
> information... Done You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to
> correct these: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
> mariadb-client : Depends: mariadb-client-10.0 (=
> 10.0.33+maria-1~trusty) but 10.0.31-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 is to be installed E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no
> packages (or specify a solution).

sudo apt-get -f install gives me:

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
> state information... Done Correcting dependencies... Done The
> following additional packages will be installed:   mariadb-client-10.0
> mariadb-client-core-10.0 mariadb-server-10.0 mariadb-server-core-10.0
> Suggested packages:   mailx mariadb-test tinyca Recommended packages:
> libhtml-template-perl The following packages will be upgraded:
> mariadb-client-10.0 mariadb-client-core-10.0 mariadb-server-10.0
> mariadb-server-core-10.0 4 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove
> and 26 not upgraded. 4 not fully installed or removed. Need to get 0
> B/11,7 MB of archives. After this operation, 9709 kB disk space will
> be freed. Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y Preconfiguring packages ...
> (Reading database ... 304724 files and directories currently
> installed.) Preparing to unpack
> .../mariadb-server-10.0_10.0.33+maria-1~trusty_amd64.deb ... Unpacking
> mariadb-server-10.0 (10.0.33+maria-1~trusty) over
> (10.0.31-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) ... dpkg: error processing archive
> /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-server-10.0_10.0.33+maria-1~trusty_amd64.deb
> (--unpack):  trying to overwrite
> '/usr/share/man/man1/mysql_upgrade.1.gz', which is also in package
> mariadb-server-core-10.0 10.0.31-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 dpkg-deb: error:
> subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe) dpkg: regarding
> .../mariadb-server-core-10.0_10.0.33+maria-1~trusty_amd64.deb
> containing mariadb-server-core-10.0:  mariadb-server-10.0 conflicts
> with mysql-server-core-5.5   mariadb-server-core-10.0 provides
> mysql-server-core-5.5 and is to be installed.
>
> dpkg: error processing archive
> /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-server-core-10.0_10.0.33+maria-1~trusty_amd64.deb
> (--unpack):  conflicting packages - not installing
> mariadb-server-core-10.0 dpkg: regarding
> .../mariadb-client-core-10.0_10.0.33+maria-1~trusty_amd64.deb
> containing mariadb-client-core-10.0:  mariadb-client-10.0 conflicts
> with mysql-client-core-5.5   mariadb-client-core-10.0 provides
> mysql-client-core-5.5 and is to be installed.
>
> dpkg: error processing archive
> /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-client-core-10.0_10.0.33+maria-1~trusty_amd64.deb
> (--unpack):  conflicting packages - not installing
> mariadb-client-core-10.0 dpkg: regarding
> .../mariadb-client-10.0_10.0.33+maria-1~trusty_amd64.deb containing
> mariadb-client-10.0:  mariadb-client-core-10.0 conflicts with
> mysql-client-5.5   mariadb-client-10.0 provides mysql-client-5.5 and
> is to be installed.
>
> dpkg: error processing archive
> /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-client-10.0_10.0.33+maria-1~trusty_amd64.deb
> (--unpack):  conflicting packages - not installing mariadb-client-10.0
> Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ... Errors were encountered
> while processing:
> /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-server-10.0_10.0.33+maria-1~trusty_amd64.deb
> /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-server-core-10.0_10.0.33+maria-1~trusty_amd64.deb
> /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-client-core-10.0_10.0.33+maria-1~trusty_amd64.deb
> /var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-client-10.0_10.0.33+maria-1~trusty_amd64.deb
> E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I'm stuck, cannot install, cannot remove, cannot update.

What should I do?

Comment: i think this more a question for serverfault stackexchange https://serverfault.com/